# Определить границы самой длинной неубывающей последовательностей чисел в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

> Дан целочисленный массив. Определить границы самой длинной неубывающей последовательностей чисел в этом массиве.

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать алгоритм

```js
function NotDecreasing(n)
{
  let count = 0;
  let max = 0;
  let result = [];

  for(let i = 1; i < n.length; i++)
  {
    if (n[i] >= n[i - 1])
    {
      count ++;
      i++;
    }
    /* Если серия прервалась */
    else
    {
      //Проверяем, не максимальная ли это была серия 
      if (count > max)
        max = count;
      /* Длина новой серии пока равна 1 */
      count = 1;
    }

  } 
  return max;
}

alert(NotDecreasing([6,7,2,3,3,6,4,2]));
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? бегишь по массиву да на каждом шаге смотришь, не убыло ли... и хранишь промежуточные и текущие макс. длину и начало. Если текущая длина больше максимальной - копируешь текущие в максимальные...

Comment: а что вы пытались сами сделать?

Comment: Что такое последовательность?

Comment: @ThisMan я пыталась реализовать поиск максимальной длины, но это тоже не получается верно. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: @Qwertiy Это числа, которые идут с определенным правилом: например 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 10 — возрастающая последовательность. 10, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1 — убывающая последовательность. Вот это имеется в ввиду.

Comment: @VerNick, я не это имел в виду.

Comment: @Qwertiy А что тогда?

Comment: @VerNick, обычно в массивах ищут подпоследовательность, которая не является непрерывной. Но в вопросе говорится просто о последовательности и ничего не говорится про непрерывность. Вот про это я и спрашивал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте сначала ваш код разберем:

```
let count = 0;
```

Почему инициализация с нуля, если дальше, при нарушении последовательности, начальное значение становится уже 1. Так, если передать **ТОЛЬКО** возрастающую последовательность, у вас ее длина будет на 1 меньше

```
let result = [];
```

Эта переменная вообще не используется

```
max = count;
```

Присвоение идет только в случае, если мы прервали последовательность, опять же если последовательность **ВСЕГДА** возрастает, будет ошибка.

```
  count ++;
  i++;
```

У вас в цикле `i` уже увеличивается, зачем еще раз увеличивать уже в теле цикла?

Попробуем исправить:

```js
function getMaxSequence(n) {
  let count = 1;
  let max = 0;

  for(let i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {
    if (n[i] >= n[i - 1]) {
      count++;
    } else {
      if (count > max) {
        max = count;
        count = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  // нужно если самая длинная последовательность была в конце
  return max > count ? max : count;
}

console.log(getMaxSequence([6,7,2,3,3,6,4,2])); // случайная
console.log(getMaxSequence([1,3,4,5])); // ТОЛЬКО возврастающая
console.log(getMaxSequence([4,3,2,1])); // ТОЛЬКО убывающая
```

Но у вас задача состоит в том, что бы **определить границы** последовательности. Думаю имеется ввиду индексы первого и последнего элемента этой последовательности. Я покажу алгоритм с двумя циклами, так как он проще и наглядней, но можно и с одним это реализовать:

```js
const getSequenceBoundaries = n => {
  // массив наших границ, где хранятся индекса начала и конца последовательности 
  const sequences = [];
  let start = 0; // индекс начала последовательности
  let end = 0; // индекс конца последовательности
  
  
  for(let i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {
    // тут все почти что как и у вас
    if(n[i] >= n[i - 1]) {
      end = i;
    } else {
      // добавляем границы в массив и переходим к новой последовательности
      sequences.push([start, end]);
      start = i;
      end = i;
    }
  }
  // добавляем самую последнюю последовательность
  sequences.push([start, end]);
  
  // а теперь просто отсортируем последоватности по длине
  return sequences.sort((a, b) =>
    // разница индексов и есть длина
    (b[1] - b[0]) - (a[1] - a[0])
  )[0];
}


console.log(getSequenceBoundaries([6,7,2,3,3,6,4,2])); // случайная
console.log(getSequenceBoundaries([1,3,4,5])); // ТОЛЬКО возврастающая
console.log(getSequenceBoundaries([4,3,2,1])); // ТОЛЬКО убывающая
```

Comment: да, в задаче нужно было найти индексы первого и последнего элемента этой последовательности. Спасибо Вам большое за детальное разъяснение моего кода, я только учусь)) Очень Вам благодарна.

Comment: @loreley не за что, обращайтесь, если что)

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант. Возвращает все последовательности по возрастанию

```
var T = [3, 45, 56, 4, 7, 8, 912, 43, 34, 6, 789, 34, -1, 0, -12, 10, 4, 7, 23, 228, 71, 40, 59, 30];


var arrays = [];
var start = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
    for (let j = start; j < T.length; j++) {
        if (j < T.length) {
            arrays.push(T.slice(start, j + 1));
        }
    }
    start++;
}
var result = arrays
.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.length > b.length) return 1;
    if(a.length == b.length) return 0;
    if(a.length < b.length) return -1;
}).reverse();

for (const key of result) {
    var N = Object.assign([], key);

    N.sort((a, b) => {
        if(a > b) return 1;
        if(a == b) return 0;
        if(a < b) return -1;
    })
    var M = 0;
    for (let z = 0; z < key.length; z++) {
        if (key[z] == N[z]) { M++; };
    }

    if (M == key.length) console.log(key);


}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, буду разбираться)